# dynamic scope in recursion function

Tags: perl, recursion

Is it better to pass args to recursive function or let dynamic scope deal with it?

```
sub rec {
  my ($arg1, $arg2 ..) = (@_);
  ..
  rec(..);
}
```

or rather:

```
sub main {
  our ($arg1, $arg2 ..) = (@_);

  sub rec {
    my $arg1 = shift;
    ..  # use $args > 1
    rec($arg1);
}
```

Since I have several rec subs in main I prefer 2nd option which doesn't require passing vars all the time and reduces amount bloated code. Said that it's probably not efficient because it will go thru every stack frame in order to resolve dynamic scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't place a named subroutine inside another. This causes problems (although `use warnings;` will find them). If you want to avoid passing a constant argument to every recursion, I recommend the following instead:

```
sub recurse {
   my ($constant, ...) = @_;

   local *_recurse = sub {
      my (...) = @_;
      ...
      _recurse(...);
      ...
   };

   _recurse(...);
}
```

(No idea why you used `our`. I switched back to `my`.)

Or with a sufficiently new version of Perl (5.16+):

```
sub recurse {
   my ($constant, ...) = @_;

   my $_recurse = sub {
      my (...) = @_;
      ...
      __SUB__->(...);
      ...
   };

   $_recurse->(...);
}
```

Whatever you do, though, don't do the following as it leaks.

```
sub recurse {
   ...
   my $_recurse;
   $_recurse = sub {
      ...
      $_recurse->(...);
      ...
   };
   ...
}
```

(The inner sub references `$_recurse` which holds a reference to the inner sub, forming a reference cycle and thus a memory leak.)

Comment: what happens when you try to reach $constant in first 2 code samples and you have already 1k stack frames? What penalties do you pay?

Comment: Lexical vars (e.g. `my`, `our`) are stored in the pad. (Other things are too.) A new pad is created for each level of recursion. Unless there's some kind of optimization here, there will be one (32-bit or 64-bit) pointer for each level of recursion. The pad is located on the heap. (So is the stack.)

Comment: does it mean that it will linearly scan (hash lookup?) all pads until it finds one? There isn't anything like global pad which you could resolve with O(log2)?

Comment: The pad is an array. The index lookup is done at compile-time. (e.g. `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $x; my $y;'`)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recursive function that relies on global variables, it can almost certainly be recoded as an iterative subroutine that uses locally scoped variables instead.

I would strongly recommend that you always pass variables and return values, and that you rethink the design of your algorithms to use iteration (`while` loops) versus recursion.

If you add details for your methods, we might be able to suggest an actual implementation.  But given the amount of information you've shared, all we can do is advise design theory.

Comment: No, it's quite common to have some parameters which don't change for the length of the recursion. e.g., `fib_to_file($fh, $n)`. It says nothing about whether it can be recoded as an iterative sub.

Comment: There is not enough information in this post to have a real discussion.  However, I suspect that the OP is over complicating his design for the wrong reasons.  To your point, yes of course there are amorphous recursive subroutines that maintain state variables through each recursion.   I just propose that a lot of new programmers use recursion simply because they can, not because they necessarily should.